# How can I have multiple views in igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controls

I want to create new view for testing purposes inside the Code igniter directory, where one view directory already exist. How can I create another view and fetch result coming from controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need new directory? I recommend you to name views like "test_NAME-OF-VIEW" and in controller use some function like "test_SOME-SECURITY-CODE_NAME-OF-FUNCTION(PAGE)"

It is possible to make new VIEW folder, but you will have to change some codeigniter system files and that's what you should not do.

> As of codeigniter 3.*+ you can make folder in **view** folder, so for example:
>   application/views/**test**/home_view.php and then load view like this:`$this->load->view("test/home_view");`

Comment: Ok, and what if i am not able to modify the controllers and create a new test_view in the homeView directory, can i still access data from model through controller or without controller ?

Comment: You can't get data from model and send it to another view without access to controller

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out of this, i just created another copy of CodeIgniter outside the WebService Directory and there it is easily accessible and i can do testing too.

`<?php echo'loudfind.com'; ?>`